# RACSignal combineLatest: cannot reduce

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, reactive-cocoa

I have a horrible compile problem while trying to reduce a couple of signals.

```
RACSignal* contactIdentifierSignal = RACObserve(self, contactIdentifier);
RACSignal* displayNameSignal = RACObserve(self, displayName);

RACSignal* mappedThing = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[contactIdentifierSignal, displayNameSignal] reduce:^id(NSString* identifierValue, NSString* displayNameValue){      
    return @([identifierValue length] > 0 && [displayNameValue length] > 0);
}];
```

The error that I get is:

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id(^)()' with an rvalue of type 'id(^)(NSString* __strong, NSString* __strong)'

[image]

According to the documentation of ReactiveCocoa, I'm supposed to have a number of params for each signal in the combine block, but it does not seem to work.

And I have no idea why this thing expects a reduce block with no parameters...

Have anyone encountered this problem before?

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#combining-latest-values

Comment: I tried this code and it compiles (ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7, Xcode 6.1.1), . Are you sure that problem is not elsewhere in your code? E.g. something's wrong with imports, or some preprocessor macros messed things up?

Comment: @MichałCiuba I think that I forgot to say that I'm inside of an ObjectiveC++ file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it looks horrible, but as I'm using Objective-C++ this thing goes crazy.

I solve this thing by casting it to *id* and it works... don't ask me why.

```
RACSignal* contactIdentifierSignal = RACObserve(self, contactIdentifier);
RACSignal* displayNameSignal = RACObserve(self, displayName);

RACSignal* mappedThing = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[contactIdentifierSignal, displayNameSignal] reduce:(id)^id(NSString* identifierValue, NSString* displayNameValue){      
    return @([identifierValue length] > 0 && [displayNameValue length] > 0);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've heard recently this error happens when using Objective-C++. Whether you're using objc++ or not, consider using `combineLatest:` and then `map:`, likely using `RACTupleUnpack`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using objective C++